# How to convert a comma-delimited string to dictionary

Tags: c#, string, dictionary

I have the following string, taken from the Resources of my project in VS2013:

```
.txt, Text Document
.exe, Application
.py, Python File
.jpg, Image File
.png, Image File
.dll, Application Extension
.js, Javascript File
.mp3, Music File
.mp4, Video File
.wmv, Video File
.ini, Configuration File
.sys, System File
.log, Log File
.rar, RAR Archive
.zip, Compressed folder
.bmp, Image File
.MSI, MSI File
.cab, cab File
.gitignore, Git Ignore File
.gitattributes, Git Attributes File
.csproj, C# Project File
.md, Markdown File
.sln, Visual Studio Solution File
```

How would I convert this into a dictionary? I figure that I'd split it on commas and newlines, but I'm having troubles working out the specifics...

Answer (score 4):

```
str.Split(new [] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
   .ToDictionary(x => x.Split(',')[0], x => x.Split(',')[1]);
```